# How to insert two brackets with a cursor in the middle in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, code-formatting

I`ve seen such kind of feature in one video on Mac. 
Is there a way to do this on Windows?

On the way of programming it would be a nice feature. I mean inserting {} or () or '' brackets at once with a cursor in the middle.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question properly...

Use [XBrackets Lite plugin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/XBrackets%20Lite/) for NP++.Also, remember to enable the Autocomplete brackets.

[image]

It does the automatic bracket closing and keeps your cursor in the middle.